# Ubuntu 18.04-Runtime error- Embedding python to C

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, numpy

I am working on a project which is related to object detection and ocr. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and python 2.7, yolov3 for object detection and tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-692-g62ea for ocr. I have to embed the python code that is for ocr into the C code for object detection. I wrote this C code and compile at the terminal by " sudo gcc code.c -lpython2.7 "

```
#include < /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h >

int main() {
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('.')");
PyRun_SimpleString("import ocr3;");
PyRun_SimpleString("print ocr3.myabs(2.0)");
Py_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

but it gives an error while running a.out:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "./ocr3.py", line 1, in
import cv2
File "/home/asus/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/init.py", line 3, in
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
NameError: name 'ocr3' is not defined
```

so, I tried another C code:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < ncurses.h >
#include < /usr/local/include/python2.7/Python.h >

int main()
{
char filename[] = "ocr3.py";
FILE* fp;

Py_Initialize();

fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

but again I have an issue while running a.out:

```
" code.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `_Py_fopen' "
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any solution. Can anyone help about the fix one of the these problems?